# Pressing two buttons at the same time, GPIO.add_event_detect

Tags: python, multithreading, button, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing

I have some functions that are called as multiprocesses. One button activates one function and the other activates a second function. How to write code so that functions can be called at the same time with two buttons?

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    running_time=0

    process1=mp.Process(target=my_callback_1(running_time))
    process2=mp.Process(target=my_callback_2(running_time))
### I want this two events called at the same time or while one function is
#   working second can be started.
    GPIO.add_event_detect(19, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback_1, bouncetime=10)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(26, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback_2, bouncetime=10)
###
```

Comment: You need your callbacks to return immediately in order for the event loop to detect / respond to other events (such as the second button being pressed). If your callback creates a thread and starts it then returns, that should all happen quite quickly, so the main thread is able to continue responding to gpio events, and the thread you just created and started can do the actual work eg: `my_callback_1`

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. You mean one more callback? Both my_callback_1 and 2 work fine, but they can't work simultaneously, or one calls functions and has to finish so that the second can start, and I want that while the first function was called, I would call the second.

Answer (score 0):

If your callbacks aren't super cpu intensive, and they just need to not block the main thread from continuing to respond to gpio input, I'd use threads:

```
from threading import Thread
def run_in_thread(func):
    def wrapped():
        t = Thread(target=func)
        t.start()
    return wrapped

GPIO.add_event_detect(19, GPIO.RISING, callback=run_in_thread(my_callback_1), bouncetime=10)
GPIO.add_event_detect(26, GPIO.RISING, callback=run_in_thread(my_callback_2), bouncetime=10)
```

If the two functions can modify data that the other might use, you'll want to use `Lock`s or some other mechanism to make sure they don't trip over each other. Depending on how robust you need this to be, it may also be a good idea to keep track of your child threads with some sort of global list of running threads. This list would allow you to check to make sure threads ran without generating errors, as well as if threads are running a long time without exiting.